# restAssured multipart need for parameters order

Tags: java, rest, testing

I am in need of forcing multipart parameters order in restAssured. However, I couldn't find anywhere if it's even possible to have some kind of sort of multipart parameters.

What I need is that my file will be last of the parameters sent. Currently, it is the first.

```
 RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost:8000/";
 RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();

 request.header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

 File file = new File("test.png");

 Map<String, String> requestParamsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
 ....someParams...

 response = request.log()
                .all()
                .formParams(requestParamsMap)
                .multiPart("file", file);
                .post("/some/endPoint");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution. I need to have all attributes as multiparts and have the file as a last multipart.

```
.multiPart("param1", "value1")
.multiPart("paramN", valueN)
.multiPart("file", file)
.post("some/endPoint");
```